# Adding eventhandlers in an accessible way

Tags: c#, accessibility

I'm blind. I have figured most things out, though, as the properties window is pretty accessible.
One thing I could not figure out (at least in Visual C# and Winforms) is how to add an eventhandler.
Let's assume we have a menu item "exit". If I select properties, I can change lots of things from font size over text alignment to accessible description, but nothing seems to match events or event handlers.
I folded out all parts of the property Window, but it's nowhere to be found.
Does anyone know where exactly I can find this in the properties window?
Or if not, where would Visual Studio add events and event handlers so I can do this manually?
I'm honestly a bit confused by all the separate files and unsure where to add what.
(Using Visua Studio 2017)

Comment: There's lightning bolt that switches between properties and events in  the property viewer.

Comment: I read as much, but so far, I could not find an accessible workaround for this however.

Comment: I would think that, being blind, it would be easier to just write out the code to do what you want (given that that's all entirely text), rather than trying to use a GUI to auto-generate code for you (which is usually not even helpful over writing the code yourself in general).

Comment: I agree, but all the tutorials and articles I found only told me what to write, not where. Can I just put the code anywhere I want? That sounds unlikely...